# How to customise UI of PiP provided in iOS/tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, picture-in-picture

Is there any way to show the error icon in PIP in case there is any error in video streaming to notify the user?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this but two possibilities seem appropriate:

1. Create a delegate for AVPictureInPictuerCoroller`and implement the`pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, failedToStartPictureInPictureWithError error: Error)` so you know that an error occurred.
   Could then show a different built-local video with one frame with the error icon.
2. (likely better) Same as above but implement delegate function:
   `pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`

and adjust your UI to display the error icon (could be over the top of the PiP std UI).

Comment: Regarding your second option, How to identify the position of PiP std UI? As per the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller its not a view.

Comment: I don't know your app design, but I'd ask: How did the user initiate the PiP from your app?  I would hide the PiP and show the error indicator in the area where they initiated PiP (icon next to the button or other control).  If the PiP content is missing there's no reason to leave the PiP display up, is there?

Comment: The pip is initiated from the full-screen player view. So will it be good behavior to take the user back to full screen when there is an error in pip?

Comment: Hmm. Hard to visualize the UX from your description.  Is there any reason to leave the PiP up?  If it can't show the video and there isn't some other video to auto-play instead, then it seems like it should close.  If there's not a button or some other obvious UI think in the primary view then probably you need to present an alert informing the user their requested action couldn't be done because the video failed to load.  Depends on the context some but that's my guess.

Comment: Consider that this error could happen immediately or part way through the video if the internet connection goes down.  So in the latter case you probably want to present an alert so it covers both cases well and the user understands what happened.